# How to check if key exists in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to check if a key exists in a MongoDB collection. Basically, I need to map an array of strings to a specific key. If the key exists, I want to update the list by adding a new value, otherwise create a new key with an initial value (If a new key is added, it will only be added with 1 value initially).

I have found some examples online, though I haven't been able to get it to work locally. Here is my code below (I am using the official Go MongoDB driver):

```
key:= "some_key"
database := client.Database("dbName")
keysCollection := database.Collection("keys")
keysCollection.Find(nil, {key:{$exists:true}});
```

I'm running into 2 issues around this component `{key: {$exists:true}}`

- `invalid character U+0024 '$'`: when trying to check if the `key` exists, at `{$exists:true}`, though this seems to be what the MongoDB documentation supports to check if the key itself exists, without checking for an exact value mapped to it
- `syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression`: at the beginning of `{key: {$exists:true}}`, it looks like I cannot pass a struct?

This is my first time working with MongoDB, and I have very little experience in GoLang, and am stuck on this seeming small issue.

Am I going about this the right way? If so, how can I move past these issues?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check if a key exists in a collection the following are the queries in `mongo` shell and *golang* respectively. Assume a collection of sample documents as:

```
{ _id: 1, arr: [ "red", "blue" ] }
{ _id: 2  }
```

*The query:*

```
db.collection.find( { "arr": { "$exists": true } } )
```

See the usage of [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/).

```
var result bson.M
filter := bson.D{{ "arr", bson.D{{ "$exists", true }} }}
err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&result)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Found a single document: %+v\n", result)
```

---

> I am trying to check if a key exists in a MongoDB collection.  I need
> to map an array of strings to a specific key.  If the key exists, I
> want to update the list by adding a new value, otherwise create a new
> key with an initial value (If a new key is added, it will only be
> added with 1 value initially).

To update a field based upon a condition, you need to use an [Update With Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/). The following shell and *golang* queries update all documents with the condition - if the array field exists, it adds the value from `newValue` *or* if the field doesn''t exist, creates a new field `arr` with the value from`newValue`.

```
var newValue = "white"

db.collection.updateMany(
  { },
  [ { 
       $set: { 
           arr: { 
               $concatArrays: [ 
                   { $ifNull: [ "$arr", [ ] ] }, 
                   [ newValue ] 
               ] 
           } 
       } 
  } ]
)
```

The *golang* update:

```
newValue := "white"
filter := bson.D{{}}

pipe := bson.D{{ "$set", bson.D{{ "arr", bson.D{{ "$concatArrays", bson.A{ bson.D{{"$ifNull",bson.A{ "$arr", bson.A{} }}}, bson.A{ newValue } } }} }} }}
    
updateResult, errr := collection.UpdateMany(ctx, filter, mongo.Pipeline{ pipe })
    
if errr != nil {
    log.Fatal(errr)
}
fmt.Printf("Matched %v documents and updated %v documents.\n", updateResult.MatchedCount, updateResult.ModifiedCount)
```

Comment: Also, refer: [MongoDB Golang Driver Tutorials](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/search/golang%20quickstart).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var res []MyType
err := keysCollection.Find(ctx, bson.M{key: bson.M{"$exists": true}}, &res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still getting the same `Invalid character` error. the `$exists` seems to be giving me issues still.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't nest the `bson.M`. I updated my answer. Check out [this](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial-part-1-connecting-using-bson-and-crud-operations) tutorial on using the BSON types. You also need to specify a pointer to where the result should be decoded into

Answer (score 0):

use the below query, we will get all results.

```
db.getCollection('botConfig').find({"Keyval":{'$exists': 1}})
or 
db.getCollection('botConfig').find({"handoffSettings":{'$exists': true}})
```

please check the docs for more [information](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#-exists).