# Insert value as soon as field updated

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a basic document versioning system. While updating a record, I should save the current field value in another field(as a list/array, so we going to use $push in MongoDB).

For example, if I want to update the user_name field, the current name should be saved to old_user_names

sample code

```
func UpdateDocument(ctx context.Context, id uuid.UUID, obj interface{}) error {

    filter := bson.M{"_id": id}

    update := bson.M{"$set": obj,
        "$push": bson.D{
            {"old_original_names", "old_original_name_here"},
        },
        "$inc": bson.M{"version": 1}}

    r.db.FindOneAndUpdate(ctx, filter, update)

    return nil
}
```

I should add the current object's name field to "current_name_here" but I couldn't figured it out.

Comment: also show the value of `obj`

Comment: obj{} is an interface that comes from the service layer

Comment: Assuming you want to update a field with a value from another field value within the same document, then you need to use the Updates With Aggregation Pipeline syntax.

Comment: @prasad_ While updating this document, I need to save the pre-updated state of the original_name. I don't wanna send a second different query to fetch that name. I I will store that names in array, so with $push

Comment: Here are some examples of using Updates with Aggregation Pipeline. (1) [How to check if key exists in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167039/how-to-check-if-key-exists-in-mongodb/68168941#68168941) (2) [How to add createAt field into Mongodb using _id as timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471191/how-to-add-createat-field-into-mongodb-using-id-as-timestamp/59476169#59476169)